# Cross compile Go binaries on Macbook Pro 2019 for Amazon AWS EC2

Tags: zsh

I need to compile Go binaries on Macbook Pro 2019 for Amazon AWS EC2 Linux instance. Here is the screenshot (I searched at many places I couldn't get an answer for it):

[image]

I tried this command on my MacBook pro:

```
sudo $GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o main
```

and I get the error:

> zsh: linux not found

[image]

I wrote this command to get a list of platforms it can cross-compile to like this and you can see there is an option for Linux too but it throws the error:

[image]

Comment: I think this is a macos/zsh question to do with env. vars.  Nothing to do with Go

Comment: @AJR, Go is a symptom of this issue. ***This question wouldn't exist if this person knew it were an issue with the way they were using environmental variables***. As far as OP is concerned, this had everything to do with Go.

Comment: `sudo` is not needed when building Go programs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the $ in front of GOOS.

GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o main

Answer (score 1):

I think you should test without this $ before GOOS

```
sudo GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o main
```

Answer (score 0):

While the answers by Russell Smith and Allan Jacquet correctly explain how to do it correctly, they don't explain, **why** you got exactly that error message.

You were bitten by two zsh properties working together: Parameter expansion, and (not so obvious) '='-expansion.

In your command

```
sudo $GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o main
```

zsh first substitutes the parameters. You have one parameter substitution here, `$GDOS`, and zsh replaces this with the content of the variable `GDOS`. Assuming this variable does not exist at this point or is empty, this results in the line

```
sudo =linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o main
```

Next step is "="-expansion, since the second word in this line starts with an equal-sign. In general, a word `=something` searches a program named *something* in the PATH and replaces that word by the full path name. You can try this feature by doing for instance a `echo =cat` (which, on my platform, outputs `/usr/bin/cat`).

Since you don't have a program named `linux` in your PATH, the command fails.

BTW, if you had enabled

```
set -u
```

in your shell, zsh would complained that you are using a variable GDOS which does not have a value yet; this would have made it obvious for you to find the error.